# QThread and Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Tags: python, pyqt

I tried using QThread for adding a tedious task of adding `QWidget` objects to my `QTreeWidget` as I thought QThread would have all the necessarities for such. But without luck! What I've been able to read about is that I cannot do sudden operations outside the `QMain` method but that there's a way to do it.

Below is a `QThread class` and a `class` that adds an item to a QTreeWidget. Which it easily can. But whenever I try to add the `QPushUpButton` it'll give me an error of parenting.

Is it impossible to achieve this with QThread?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread

class YourThreadName(QThread):

def __init__(self, QTreeWidget, obj):
    QThread.__init__(self)
    self.Tree = QTreeWidget
    self.obj = obj
def __del__(self):
    self.wait()

def run(self):
    item = qt.QTreeWidgetItem()
    item.setText(0, "hi")

    self.Tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

    bttn = qt.QPushButton("Graph")
    bttn.clicked.connect(self.obj.printer)
    bttn.setObjectName("Test")

    self.Tree.setItemWidget(item, 1, bttn)

class Window(qt.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

    frameWrapper = qt.QFrame(self)    
    self.setCentralWidget(frameWrapper)

    self.frameAlgorithm = qt.QFrame(frameWrapper)
    self.frameAlgorithm.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 400)
    self.faLayout = qt.QGridLayout(self.frameAlgorithm)

    bttn = qt.QPushButton("Add Rows", self)
    bttn.clicked.connect(self.StartThread)
    self.faLayout.addWidget(bttn, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    self.Tree = qt.QTreeWidget()
    self.Tree.setHeaderLabels(["Name", "Button"])
    self.faLayout.addWidget(self.Tree, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    self.setGeometry(600, 400, 700, 400)
    self.show()

def StartThread(self):    
    qThread = YourThreadName(self.Tree, self)
    qThread.start() 

def printer(self):
    print(self.sender().objName())

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Interacting with GUI objects from a thread will lead to unpredictable behaviour and random application crashes. It is not safe to do what you are doing. I strongly recommend you don't use a thread.

Comment: @three_pineapples What else is there to do? If my GUI have to make 1000 lines in a QTreeWidget, it will freeze the application for a long time, making the app kinda bad.

Comment: @vandelay. 1000 lines is not a large number of items. I strongly suspect you are engaging in premature optimisation and you haven't actually timed anything.

Comment: @three_pineapples Well it could be an arbritage amount of lines. I tried creating a WidgetTree with 74000 lines, and it took enough time to make the application to sorta freeze out. There's also alot of gathering data which adds to it. The code I posted is just an example.

Comment: @vandelay. Then don't load all the items at once. If the items are nested, add the child items when the parent is expanded. If the items are not nested, load them in batches when the scroll position changes.

Comment: @ekhumoro Well that's a possibility. But I'd really like to have some sort of threading with signals working. It would really smooth my application out.

Comment: @vandelay. As has already been explained, you **cannot** safely use multi-threading for *any* gui operations. Do yourself a favour and spend some time doing some proper [profiling](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) so you can see where the real performance bottle-necks are in your program. If the large majority of the time is spent rendering the gui, multi-threading will be of no use whatsoever.